# Getting all instance of a class in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Good morning, i am creating a vending machine and i would like to display a 'Shopping Cart' of all my item with more than 0 in quantity.I managed to do the whole machine etc, and i'm having issue on the Cart section. I don't know ,and can't find how to display all object in a class. Can you help me?
This is a sample of my code that i simplified for this question. Note that the amount are suposed to be variables changing.

```
#Vending Machine
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x800')
style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme("arc")

frame = Frame(root,background='#F0F0F0',bd=2,relief=GROOVE)
frame.pack(side=LEFT)

##########CLASS FOR EACH PRODUCT##########
class Product:
    #                 name/image/    price/Image row/Image Column/amount/Amount row/Amount Column/price row/price column/Pbtn row/Pbtn column/Mbtn row/Mbtn
    def __init__(self,name,imagepath,price,Dr,Dc,Unit,D_amount_r,D_amount_c):
        self.name = name
        self.imagepath = imagepath
        self.Image = PhotoImage(file=imagepath)
        self.Unit = Unit
        
        ###########PRICE##########
        self.price = price
        Dprice = ttk.Label(frame,text=self.price, font=15, background='#F0F0F0')

        ##########PICTURE##########
        self.Dr = Dr
        self.Dc = Dc
        display = Label(frame,image=self.Image)
        display.grid(row=Dr, column=Dc)

        ##########AMOUNT##########
        self.amount = IntVar()
        self.amount.set(self.Unit)
        self.D_amount_r = D_amount_r
        self.D_amount_c = D_amount_c
        self.D_Amount = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=self.amount,font=10, padding=10, background='#F0F0F0')
        self.D_Amount.grid(row=D_amount_r, column=D_amount_c)

P001 = Product('ChocolateBar','Images\ChocolateBar.png',   25,0,1,0,3,1)
P002 = Product('AlmondBar','Images\AlmondBar.png',         35,0,5,2,3,5)
P003 = Product('CoconutBar','Images\CoconutBar.png',       35,0,9,0,3,9)
P004 = Product('AppleJuice','Images\AppleJuice.png',       40,4,1,6,7,1)
P005 = Product('MangoJuice','Images\Mangojuice.png',       40,4,5,4,7,5)
P006 = Product('CoconutWater','Images\CoconutWater.png',   40,4,9,5,7,9)
P007 = Product('AppleJam','Images\AppleJam.png',           35,8,1,3,10,1)
P008 = Product('PearJam','Images\PearJam.png',             35,8,5,0,10,5)
P009 = Product('BananaChips','Images\BananaChips.png',     60,8,9,1,10,9)

root.mainloop()
```

This is what i would like to do:[Shopping Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv4WT.png)

Comment: "I don't know ,and can't find how to display all object in a class. "  It is *your responsibility* to keep track of the objects you are interested in. For example, by using some sort of container, like a `list` or a `dict` to aggregate objects. You then use that container whenever you need to manipulate those objects as a group

Comment: If i understand correctly , i must create a list that i will append after each new object filled in for example?

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a good idea. In this case, you can just write something like `ps = [Product(...), Product(...), ...., Product(...)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your question I understand you want to find all instances of your class that has quantity > 0?

If that's the case I would just create a list of type Product and use a for loop to check which products have quantities of at least 1.

```
product_list = [P001, P002, P003] #etc
for i in product_list: 
    if i.ammount > 0: 
        print(i.name)
```